# NServiceBus example step to step.?

Tags: c#, .net, queue, msmq, nservicebus

In my application i want to use NServiceBus.dll to read write message queue.
I googled to get the step by step tutorial but i did not get.

I want to build a console base application to read write queue using NServiceBus.
Please provide good example or link which will illustrate me NServiceBus in details.

Comment: Would someone please reopen so that this link can be added https://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/

Answer (score 3):

Why not download the NServiceBus samples and run them?

http://docs.particular.net/samples/

Comment: @Downvoter: Why do you downvote the answer. Leave a comment

Comment: I am guessing the downvote was from the submitter and that he had already tried the samples route.